# Qt application gets freezed dealing with huge dynamic data

Tags: qt

i have issues in showing huge data in QTableView ,data read from sqlite database which is being updated dynamically .. 2k rows in 2s.
i am using QSQLRelationModel
let me describe the scenario in detail.

My Qt application has a view i.e QTableView , each row has following structure:

---

*QPushButton*|QLabel | QLabel | QLabel *

---

i have created it using QItemDelegate

each row isinserted dynamicaly , after sometime gui gets freezed.

could anyone tell me the way to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, you're creating a *lot* of unnecessary delegates with the `QLabels`. That's guaranteed to waste resources and cost a lot of time allocating them.

Comment: Unfortunately, `QTableView` doesn't seem to have an equivalent to the `batchSize` property that `QTreeView` uses. :-/

Comment: The whole point of delegates in item view is avoid creating thousands of widgets -- it looks like you're going straight against that design?